# Regarding transforming Keras Theano implementation into Keras Tensorflow implemenation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

Keras application can use either Theano and Tensorflow as backend.
Are there any difference between these two implementations? I have seen a lot of Keras applications with Theano as backend. But I did not see a lot of Theano-dependent usages in these implementations.

The only item that I can quickly think of is that
For Theano, the image data set is represented as (`batchsize,channel, width, height)`
For Tensorflow, the image data set is represented as `(batchsize,width,height,channel)`

I am asking this question is because, if I see a Keras implementation with Theano as backend, what are the general modifications that I need to make, to transfer them into a one that can be run with Tensorflow as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the differences are summarized in the [documentation page](https://keras.io/backend/). In particular, some of the layers accept `tf` or `th` as `dim_ordering` parameter, regarding the order of dimensions of the image.